# Setup an email notification to admin when triggered sends exceed a level of 500 queued?

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, soap-api

In Salesforce Marketing Cloud, how might one go about setting up an email notification to admin distribution group when any of the triggered sends exceed a level of 500 queued? I would imagine that it would be a way to listen for that as a soap envelope response message. I know it's not technically an "error", but could there be  corresponding error code for triggered sends getting stuck in queued status? I've checked the [marketing cloud api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/12000_12099_subscriber_object.htm) area and don't see anything on it. Please let me know if I am looking not looking in the right location.

Comment: I believe you need to set something up with Support to monitor this.

Comment: Yes, I have inquired but am waiting for them to provide a write up of what is involved. Alternatively, they mentioned we check with internal team in-house where our infrastructure team could setup a scheduler to parse records for this type of queued status messaging provided it is communicated back during an api call in system logs and when a count of 500 is exceed, it will dispatch a mail notification job on the exchange server and send a custom alert message to a group mailbox (distribution list) and the threshhold can be adjusted if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a script activity to pull in this data and then run a verification step in an automation to deploy an email whenever that threshold has been crossed based on data you can house in a separate data extension.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
//Get Triggered Send Queue Count
var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "TriggeredSendSummary");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Queued");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CustomerKey");
var sfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "Property", "CustomerKey");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp, "Value", "Triggered_Send_Key");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", sfp);
var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);
var rQueued = rows[0].Queued;
var key = rows[0].CustomerKey;
//Write Queue Count to Lookup Table for Email Send
    if(rQueued > 500) {
    var rows = Platform.Function.InsertData("QUEUE_LOOKUP",["customer_key","current_queue"],["Triggered_Send_Key",rQueued]);
    }else{
         var rows = Platform.Function.DeleteData('QUEUE_LOOKUP',["customer_key"], ["Triggered_Send_Key"]);
    }
```

Comment: Sweet. I think we can turn this into an automated report with WSProxy in a Script Activity.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Were you able to turn this into an automated report? If so, did you publish any articles/documentation on it? Couldn't find anything on your blog

Comment: Yes.  It's very similar to the Send script but with the [TriggeredSendSummary](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/d0488d44734bce9fbb182bf7abef77a3) Object.  The automation uses a query to classify/limit the results and the email loops through and displays the rows resulting from the query.